# Bash script creates a file which it shouldn't be

Tags: bash, output-redirect

This following script will creates a file named "Happy", i couldn't figure out why, can someone try this script and tell me what is happening?
Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

str1=""
str2="Sad"
str3="Happy"

if [ "$str2">"$str3" ]
    then echo "$str2 is greater than $str3"
elif [ "$str2"<"$str3" ]
    then echo "$str2 is less than $str3"
fi
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You are redirecting the output of the command $str2 to a file named $str3. `>` in this case is not a comparison but redirection.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the link, it found the problem automatically, good tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is just a (silly) alias for the `test` command; everything following it (including the mandatory closing `]`) is an argument. (What you have is treated the same as `if test "$str2">"$str3"`.)

There are two issues:

1. The operands and the operators need to be separated by whitespace.

   ```
   # still not quite right, but ...
   if [ "$str2" > "$str3" ]
   ```
2. Since `>` and `<` are interpreted as redirection operators by the shell, they have to be escaped so that they are passed as arguments to `[`.

   ```
   if [ "$str2 \> "$str3" ]
   ```

(You might think just escaping the operator would be sufficient; however, `"$str2"\>"$str3"` would be treated as a single string argument to `test` rather than three separate arguments which `test` will interpret as an expression. `test "$str2"\>"$str3"` would simply check if the single argument is empty or not.)

Since you are using `bash`, it's far simpler to just use `[[` instead of `[`. `[[` is not a regular command; it's special syntax recognized by `bash`, so that normal processing rules don't apply. Most relevant here is that `>` is a string comparison operator, not a redirection operator, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

```
    if [[ $str2 > $str3 ]]
```

Comment: @slevy1 Nothing on that page contradicts what I've said. `>` doesn't need to be escaped inside `[[ ]]` or `(( ))`, because both are special shell constructs that are not subject to normal parsing and evaluation rules. In fact, that page *explicitly* states that both `>` and `<` require escaping when used as string comparison operators with `[`.

Comment: @chepner  Thanks! That answered my question

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite the code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

    str1=""
    str2="Sad"
    str3="Happy"

    if [[ "$str2" > "$str3" ]]
        then echo "$str2 is greater than $str3"
    elif [[ "$str2" < "$str3" ]]
        then echo "$str2 is less than $str3"
    fi
```

then the comparisons should occur correctly and you can avoid inadvertent file creation.  The extra pair of "[" and "]" takes the code out of test context, allowing for comparison and avoids file creation.  More info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) which states the following:

> Note that the ">" needs to be escaped within a [ ] construct. 
>   ... 
>   Note that the "<" needs to be escaped within a [ ] construct.

The reason is that in a test context, i.e. using only a single pair of square brackets as in the OP code,  ">" and "<" are interpreted as [redirection operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators). So, instead of meaning greater than and less than respectively, ">" means direct the output of a command to a file whereas "<" means give input to a command.